# Are C++ Containers exception-safe?

Tags: c++, containers

I use the implicit Constructor and a `load()` Member which inputs the Attributes, but can also throw exceptions.

My question is: if the Attributes are everyday C++ Containers will I get memory leaks if exceptions happen in `load()`?

Thank you for reading.

Edit: example code to help clarify my question.

```
class One
{
public:
    std::vector<int> stuff;

    void load() {
        stuff.resize(13);
        stuff[0] = 43;

        std::bad_alloc ba;
        throw ba; // will this cause memory leaks? (as far as this class is concerned)
    }
}
```

I know this is a silly question but I had to ask it.

Comment: What is `load`? No standard C++ container has that member.

Comment: I think the answer is: yes, standard containers are exception-safe.  But could you add some representative code to your question, so we know exactly what you're talking about?

Comment: Does `container == standard container`?

Comment: @Billy: `load` custom member for a custom class.  
@Oli: this was a generic question, I don't have any code to share.  
@iammilind: yes.

Comment: @catfish: It is not clear whether you have a container as a member variable of your class, or whether the container is used to store instances of your class, and how the `load()` member function fits into this.  Some pseudocode would help clarify this.

Comment: @catfish: Then how would we have known what the semantics of `load` are? Your question didn't make sense. Even now it's confusing but at least I think it's decypherable now...

Comment: Exception-safety of containers deals with whether operations *on* the container will leave the container in a consistent and predictable state. Your code has nothing to do with the exception-safety of the container. Nothing to do with containers at all, actually. You could use *any* class in place of `vector`; you're just asking whether an escaping exception will cause a local variable to be destroyed.

Answer (score 10):

The container itself is exception safe.
But it also depends on the type being placed in the contain and if it has been written correctly.

i.e.: Exceptions should not escape the destructor

The standard defines the following guarantees on containers and exceptions:

#### 23.2.1   General container requirements  [container.requirements.general]

Paragraph 10:

> Unless otherwise specified (see 23.2.4.1, 23.2.5.1, 23.3.3.4, and 23.3.6.5) all container types defined in this Clause meet the following additional requirements:
> — if an exception is thrown by an insert() function while inserting a single element, that function has no effects.
> — if an exception is thrown by a push_back() or push_front() function, that function has no effects.
> — no erase(), clear(), pop_back() or pop_front() function throws an exception.
> — no copy constructor or assignment operator of a returned iterator throws an exception.
> — no swap() function throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, containers are exception safe. As long as you aren't doing shenanigans like allocating them on the heap (without exception-safe smart pointers) or such like that, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question doesn't state much, here is my take.

If you are allocating memory using `new/new[]` (inside your `load()`) then you have to deallocate using `delete/delete[]`, when exception is thrown.

If you are allocating as an automatic variable then they are exception safe.